# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, activeandroid

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT Show in Project
>   Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is liable to **being put on hold** since you provided zero explanation on your question title (which is a particular error). You can keep the error message as the question title, but can you please give an explanation of how your program was at the time you saw this error, such as your project, files, etc, and what action lead to that error.

Answer (score 3):

You should add into app/gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    ....
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Framework was recently removed from the repository, so:

Step 1 :
remove or comment following line from build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Step 2:
Download [jar from this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1czgtBl0b4wxNMlF0OF2iCoGjcxeN6KTp/view?usp=sharing)

Step 3:
Put this jar to app/lib folder

Step 4 :
add implementation files('libs/activeandroid-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar') line to build.gradle file

Comment: The jar file is no more available. Anybody has a valid link ? Or please upload it again somewhere, for example on Github. Thanks.

Comment: @toto_tata check link again.